# Windows application saving data into multiple tables

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am currently working on C# using entity framework,

I have 2 tables named `Tab_1` and `Tab_2`.
While clicking save button, table `Tab_1` saves, after that I have to add `Tab_1's` last entered primary key value, to be saved to the  1st column of the `Tab_2`.

I tried this but I am getting error.

sample code:

```
Tab_1 t1 = new Tab_1();
//t1.a1 is auto generated primary key
t1.a = txt1.Text;
t1.b = text = txt2.Text;
context.tab_1.AddObject(t1);
context.savechanges();

Tab_2 t2 = new Tab_2();
t2.id = t1.a1;
t2.name = txt3.Text;
context.savechanges();
```

The last line `context.savechanges()` unfortunately raises the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '

Comment: post some code and error which you are getting?

Comment: check exception description, and post the exception with innerException and trace.

Comment: thank you i got the required output:)